# Why are standard windows (sashes) so hard and expensive to replace?

Tags: windows, glass

I have double hung vinyl windows. They each can slide up and down and you can pull them out as well. I have a sticker on one of the sashes which even gives the sash dimensions: 25 3/8 x 26 1/16.

To my amazement, there is no standardization of size, so I can't just go into a store and get a replacement. Neither is it easy, if possible online, to get one made and sent from a generic manufacturer, because I don't know the maker of mine. There is no standardization like in almost every other field.

On top of that I'm even told by multiple parties, if you get a new window of a reputable manufacturer, and get a crack in a sash pane, you'd replace the whole window anyway.

This makes no sense to me because even a child could remove and switch out a cracked window sash if he had a replacement, based on their clever latch design. Why even go to the trouble of inventing that?

Why would an entire window replacement be necessary when the rest of the window frame is in perfectly good working order. This is not how construction is done in any other area.

On top of that, windows are insanely expensive. Home Depot quoted about $1400 for a replacement, and that's on the low end. They can run 3k per window, and how many windows does a house have?

I was told I could get the glass alone repaired at a hardware store. I called my nearest store and they said they could, for only around $30. I'd be willing to pay more. Their problem is they said it wouldn't be able to be worked on until October (it's august now), just because they are so busy, yet I'd still have to bring it in today and leave it with them to get on the wait list, leaving myself without a window for weeks.

None of any of this makes any sense to me and I'm still looking for solutions. I'm going to call other glass repair outfits but nothing in this makes sense to me. I get the desire for profit but you'd think there'd be a market for generic non oem sash makers or something.

All I need is to replace a pane because of a crack, but if I leave it as is, it's perfectly functional. How can a crack cost me over $1000, and since my house has 15+ windows, it's significant financial exposure for so little a thing - a bird from outside or a clumsy person from inside.

I know now, after the inspector, that I probably don't have tempered glass or gas filled insulation.

What would you all do to repair and maintain and keep things looking nice without breaking the bank or waiting for weeks and months, and to keep things in good shape?

[image: windows used]

Comment: You'll have to thin this down to something in scope for this site See https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. As it is, this is mostly rant, which does feel good, but is off-topic. And "What would you all do" is rather opinion-based, which is also off-topic. A more on topic question: "How can I replace a window pane because of a crack?"

Comment: Your photo is too small to be able to see any real detail, but the glass had to be fit into the frame by some method, either from the inside or outside. Just buy a new pane of glass & refit it the same way. It will either be a clip-in strip [which *should* be on the inside so burglars can't get in] or old-fashioned putty on the outside. You can get glass cut to size just about anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've hit on one of the main reasons I dislike vinyl windows--they're not standard or well supported unless you happen to buy from one of the few reputable, long-lived companies. Therefore, repair is often simply impossible. I have the same problem in my three-season porch with failing sashes and weather seals. In the rest of the house I can get Andersen replacement parts fairly easily.

To clarify further, consumer demand for the cheapest possible product has resulted yet again in a symptom of #throwawayculture. Your windows, in short, are disposable. (Don't blame builders. They install what consumers want to pay for.) It's a short-sighted approach to both economy and effects on the environment.

Comment: Amen on the 'long-lived' assessment. I had a bad window at my last house. It was 20 years old. Since it was from a reputable company, I bought a replacement part from the local glass store and popped it right in. With a noname builder brand, good luck doing that.

Comment: Do they make them differently in the US? All UK glazing is done similar to this, no matter who it's made by - the bit I've coloured green just clips in & out - https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pfDt.jpg When the seal went on one of my panes after 20 years, I just rang the nearest glass shop & ordered a replacement double-glazed unit. All you need are dimensions & air-gap size. Took two days to arrive on my doorstep. Fitting took 30 minutes, 20 of those were finding the right spudger substitute to get the clips out without damaging the rubber seals.

Comment: Amazing answer. I didn't mean this to sound like a rant but a broad range of solutions or confirmation that this is how things are, which you gave me.  Btw I found a guy that fixed the glass from his van. He came within the hour and finished the job for just over 100, replacing the pane. I'd like to learn his skills

Comment: He replaced a _pane_, or the entire sealed unit? (I assume you have double-glazed windows as is the modern standard.)

Comment: He cut and pulled out the cracked glass pane, the outer one, and cut a new one to size. I didn't see all he did, the beginning and end but saw the glass cutting parts. He cleaned thoroughly and was quiet and professional. I don't know how he worked with the vinyl but it looks good. He set it in the basement where it was cooler because he told me the warm air could humidify in the winter. He gave me other options, involving part ordering or doing it in a cooler season. Obviously there's no insulating argon gas but I don't think there was before. I do have double glazed double hung